# How do I automate data export in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

After some slicing and dicing, I end up with a relatively small data set which I want to handle off-line. I end up writing this:

```
store foo into 'foo' using PigStorage('\t');
copyToLocal foo foo;
rm foo; 
sh cat foo/part* | sort -k... -o foo.tsv;
sh rm -rf foo;
```

I would like to replace these 5 lines with a macro call, but it does not
look like I can - I get `Unexpected character '|'` when I do.

So, can I avoid repeating these 5 lines a few times in every script?

Comment: btw, you don't have to specify "using PigStorage('\t')". It is used by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the shell command with quotes.
I don't remember the syntax exactly. Something like:

```
sh bash "your commands"
```

If this doesn't work for you, I think you can put your commands in a separate shell executable and invoke it from Pig.

Answer (score 1):

[I cannot](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/cont.html#define-macros):

> The shell commands (used with Grunt) are not supported.

not even `copyToLocal` appears to be allowed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Basically it seems that you are going in the wrong way. Those shell commands would be handy when you work with Pig interactively (in the Grunt shell), but you are trying to encapsulate non-pig stuff into the Pig script that you want to run many times (non-interactively). I would go the other way around. I'd encapsulate that stuff (file operations/preparations as an example) into a shell/Python script and would invoke a Pig script from there along with the other stuff, keeping the Pig script inself clean.